# Android: Save/Load an ArrayList of gson.JsonObjects?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have the following `Cart` class with and array list of `mCartItems` with are gson.JsonObjects.

```
public class Cart {
    private ArrayList<JsonObject> mCartItems;
    private Context mContext;
    ...
}

// Save cart singleton to disk
    public void saveToDisk(){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(mCartItems);
            os.close();
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Saving cart to disk");

        } catch (IOException io){
            mContext.deleteFile(FILE_NAME);
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Error saving cart to disk", io);
        }
```

When I save the cartItems, I am getting the error `java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.gson.JsonObject`. How would I store the list of cart items on the file without subclassing JsonObject?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the API](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#toString()), `toString()` on a `JsonObject` gives you a `String` which is a valid Json representation on the object.

A `String` *is* serializable, and when you read it back from the disk, you can just parse it back into a `JsonObject`.

It should be fairly simple to add conversion steps to your `saveToDisk()` (and whatever `readFromDisk()` method you've got) to change your `ArrayList<JsonObject>` to an `ArrayList<String>` and back again.

Answer (score 1):

As rightly mentioned in an earlier answer , calling toString() on a JsonObject will serialize it and then you can use the same string to deserialize it as well. As an example you could do the following -

Convert the List to List by just calling toString on the objects of the initial list and then save the new list to the disk.

Also when reading from the disk , you need to convert the List to List which you could do easily by calling gsom.fromJson method supplying the string.

There could be other efficient ways as well of doing this , which you can find out. I wanted to emphasize that JsonObject is readily serializable.